# cakephp - debugger error using imagecreatefrompng()

Tags: php, cakephp, imagecreatefrompng

I have some code which breaks when I use imagecreatefrompng() in an action in my controller. I don't think it should make a difference but the imagecreatefrompng() is called inside an action which has been called via AJAX.

```
$imgName='img/favicons/'.$saveFileName.'_large.png';
$img=imagecreatefrompng($imgName);
```

I'm pretty sure the path is right. In the same action I save a file to that very folder, however I get returned the following errors:

> **Warning**:  get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, resource given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php** on line **578**
>
> **Warning**:  get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, resource given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php** on line **584**

The particular function in the debugger.php file that the errors point to handles object to string conversion, and the lines which cause the error are:

```
$className = get_class($var);
$objectVars = get_object_vars($var);
```

Anyone have any ideas what's going wrong? Thanks

**EDIT :**

Here's the code for the function

```
public function saveSiteFavicon() {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $url = $this->request->data['websiteurl'];
    $saveFileName = parse_url($url);
    $saveFileName = $saveFileName['host'];
    $saveFileName = str_replace('.', '', $saveFileName);
    $saveFileName = str_replace('www', '', $saveFileName);
    $this->Favicon->recursive = 0;
    $faviconexists = $this->Favicon->findByImage($saveFileName.'.png');
    if(!empty($faviconexists)) {
        echo $saveFileName.'.png:'.$faviconexists['Favicon']['id'];
    } else {
        $fp = fopen ('img/favicons/'.$saveFileName.'.png', 'w+');
        $ch = curl_init('http://g.etfv.co/'.$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
        /* Save the returned data to a file */
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
        //if the favicon is oversized resize it
        $faviconFileName = 'img/favicons/'.$saveFileName.'.png';
        $metaData=getimagesize($faviconFileName);
        if($metaData[1] > 16) {
            rename($faviconFileName, 'img/favicons/'.$saveFileName.'_large.png');
            $imgName='img/favicons/'.$saveFileName.'_large.png';
            $thumbName='img/favicons/'.$saveFileName.'.png';
            $img=imagecreatefrompng($imgName);
            
            $imgThumb=imagecreatetruecolor(16,16);
            imagecopyresampled($imgThumb,$img,0,0,0,0,16,16,$metaData[0],$metaData[1]);
            imagepng($imgThumb, $thumbName);
            imagedestroy($imgThumb);
        }
        $this->Favicon->create();
        $this->Favicon->save(array('image'=>$saveFileName.'.png'));
        $faviconid = $this->Favicon->getLastInsertId();
        echo $saveFileName.'.png:'.$faviconid;
    }
}
```

and in the view I just call this function via ajax and alert the results which is where I see the error messages.

```
$.post("../favicons/saveSiteFavicon", {websiteurl: value})
                .done(function(data) {
                    alert(data);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errormessage basically tells you the problem;

`$img` is a 'resource', not an `Object` or a 'simple' datatype (string/integer etc). Debugging resources is not possible. You can use `var_dump()` but this will probably only give you something like `resource #123`. Debugging the 'type' of resource may be possible by using this;

```
debug(get_resource_type($img));
```

But, looking at your code, you're already expecting that to be an 'image', or `FALSE` if `imagecreatefrompng()` failed :)

More information on 'resources';
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. I'm still a bit confused though. If I turn off the debug then I don't get error messages but either way the problem remains that imagecreatefrompng() doesn't appear to work. The path is correct as far as I can work out and the permissions on the folder are ok too since I'm able to write and rename files in that folder. What could be causing imagecreatefrompng() not to work? Sorry if I seem stupid, bit of a newbie with php and cakephp in particular.

Comment: Debug is causing the error because it is *trying* to get determin the 'class' of `$img`, which fails because it's not an `$object`. What other code is in your view? If you're trying to output an image *inside* a View, you *cannot* combine it with other output (HTML)

Comment: I've posted some code in the original question. Thank you for helping me with this, it's been doing my head in for days. I just don't understand why imagecreatefrompng() fails!

Comment: I'm sorry to keep hassling you but I'm desperate. Any ideas what my problem might be? Anything obvious?

Comment: There's so much code, all in a single function, and so many places that things can go wrong; the download may fail, saving/moving the download may fail. And, there's nowhere you're checking if the downloaded file actually is a PNG image, you seem to 'assume' it's a PNG. I'd suggest to split this function into separate functions so that you can test the various parts separately (e.g. Try to download a favicon and check it works, Resize an image that you out somewhere yourself and *know* it's a PNG)

Comment: I have tested and everything in the function works ok. The cURL bit saves the file as a png so the file I'm attempting to resize is definately a png. I've commented out bits and tested it and the bit that breaks it is imagecreatefrompng(). If I comment that line out then the whole function works as desired. Really annoying.

Comment: Well, you're using relative paths for all your filenames, so maybe imagecreatefrompng() is unable to find the file?. However, if `$img` is a 'resource' (your original question) `imagecreatefrompng()` *was* able to parse the image. Anyway, this discussion is way off-topic, the question was why the debugger was giving errors when debugging `$img`. That question is answered, I gave some pointers to find the cause of the other problems. Create a test-case with only the *minimum* of code required (without download  etc) and create a new question on stackoverflow if you still have problems

Comment: I finally figured out, with your help (thank you) that in fact the image wasn't a png despite me being pretty sure it as being created as a png. Several days and a lot of headbanging later. Thanks very much for your time :)